# Ruby detect if a column value has changed

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So I have this line:

```
if self.company_changed?
```

And it works fine but this detects if the company has changed on the object. I need to know if the database value has changed and not if the value in memory has changed. So I tried this:

```
if :company_changed?
```

This seems to work in debug mode when I only execute the one line. If I let it run, it fails in testing on an infinite loop.

My question is what can be used in ruby to check to see if the column value has actually changed.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What is a column? are you using the mysql gem? Are you using Rails or something? `if :ads` is always true. Please consider think again in your problems and start explaining from the beginning.

Comment: I am confused. :( Could you show the method `company_changed?`? Is ROR based? then tag it as `ROR`.

Comment: It is a ROR method. The column is company. The company_changed? Is generated by active record.

Comment: If you don't understand a question, ask for more info. Don't just troll the internet downvoting and voting to close. That is what makes people leave the site.

Comment: @JonathanO please consider reading [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [excellent screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/109-tracking-attribute-changes) on this by the great Ryan Bates.

Comment: This screen cast answered me perfectly

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you're actually talking about ActiveRecord. In which case, you'd need to re-fetch the record to see if the value has changed in the database.

```
self.class.find(self.id).company != self.company
```

A general purpose method for this might be something like:

```
def attr_changed_in_db?(attr)
  self.class.find(self.id).attributes[attr] != self.attributes[attr]
end
```